# Laravel config:clear Caused Crash

Tags: laravel

After running php artisan config:clear my site is now stuck on a "This page isn’t working example.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500".

I have tried restarting apache, power cycling the server, and looking in error logs.

I don't know what to do!

Comment: Neither do we with this information. Please take a look at [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the similar issue in past don't know what caused it but as of now you can delete the config.php from /vendor it won't break your code.
And your code will be start working..